# How to subscribe to an observable that subscribes to another observable and collide on next's in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I'm creating a service that requires info about a part of the current path. So, in my component, I have to take a peek at the route and **as it's completed** I need to subscribe to the actual service call like shown below.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.activeRoute.paramMap
    .subscribe(next => this.itemService.getItem(next.get("id"))
      .subscribe(next => this.item = next));
}
```

The reason for me being uncertain whether it's a good approach, is that both the services return an observable instance, which forces me to use next in two contexts, where one is within the other. Lint mentions that I'm hiding the outer *next* behind the inner.

It **seems** to work as is but buying Enron stock also **seemed** like a good idea. What worries me are two things. One's that such a warning might be (doesn't have to, though) be a sign of a bad design that hold only because of a coincidence. Second's that sooner or later, I might need to access both the *next* values for some requirement and what do I do then?

1. Is the above best-practice for such call?
2. How do I access the outer *next* in the inner context?

Comment: You need use switchMap https://blog.angularindepth.com/when-to-use-switchmap-dfe84ac5a1ff

Comment: @Eliseo Would you mind to elaborate a bit and post it as a reply so it can eventually be accepted, please? That was very advanced topic. Also, if you choose to answer, make sure to target the actual two question formulations so it's easier to digest the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea is

```
this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(switchMap((param: ParamMap) => {
      //Not return params
      let id: number = param.has('id') ? parseInt(param.get('id')) : 0;
      //return this.itemService.getItem(id)
      return this.itemService.getItem(id)
    }))
    .subscribe((item:any)=>{
      this.item=item
    })
```

See that there are a uniq subscribe

NOTA:If not work, your idea is ok (sometimes I'd have problem with paramMap and switchMap)